# How to set Overflow Menu position in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-toolbar, overflow-menu

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms project and my `Overflow Menu` is covering the `Toolbar` control when it is opened on Android device.

Usually I'm able to solve it by seting `overlapAnchor` in `actionOverflowMenuStyle` to false like this:

```
<item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
```

but in this case it doesn't work any more. Is there any other solution?

Comment: How did you write your `overflow Menu`? Please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I was missing the reference to `android:theme` in my Toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set appcompat theme for parent attribute in overflow style

```
  <style name="YourOverflowStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
  </style>
```

And you should also reference this style in your Toolbar like this

```
android:theme="@style/YourOverflowStyle"
```